# Error 1064 when import stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, import

I use the following code to import a stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `t_addToFlux`(IN `type` VARCHAR(255), IN `element_id` INT(11), IN `etudiant_id` INT(11))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO stream(type, element_id, student_id) VALUES(type, element_id, etudiant_id);
END$$
```

But when I execute it on my server I get this error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE `t_addToFlux`(IN `type` VARCHAR(255), IN `element_id` INT(11), IN `etu' at line 6

And I have no idea why this error appears

The structure of the `stream` table :

[image]

Created by :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stream` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `element_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `student_id` (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

`MySQL Version : 5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Thank you for your help !

Thomas

Comment: The definer should be wrapped in single quotes not back ticks `` so it should be `DEFINER='root'@'localhost'`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I already tried but I get the same error

Comment: post the create table for `flux`

Comment: is id auto_increment ?

Comment: @amdixon Yes it is !

Comment: @amdixon The problem can from from my MySQL Version ?

Comment: copy+paste of your create table followed by your proc definition works exactly for me

Comment: see if you can create a trivial stored procedure as in this **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44e10/1)**

Comment: @amdixon Yes I can !

Comment: ok it could be to do with your insert statement then.. as good practice anyway, you should specify the fields your inserting values into. change it to this and see if it works

Comment: @amdixon I edit my post with the new procedure, still does not work

Comment: again copy+paste of that works on mine ( 5.5 ). recommend searching through the 5.6 bug reports and if not there filing this one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution of my problem, I wrote it here if it can help some people.

My first request was :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `t_addToFlux`(IN `type` VARCHAR(255), IN `element_id` INT(11), IN `etudiant_id` INT(11))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO stream(type, element_id, student_id) VALUES(type, element_id, etudiant_id);
END$$
```

I tried to remove :

> OR REPLACE

And now my request works for me !

The fact is `"OR REPLACE"` statement does not work with MySQL.

Comment: think the issue is the OR REPLACE ( which wasnt in the question.. ). think definer is ok

Comment: @amdixon Yes, my fault ! In the question I copy paste the stored procedure from a wrong file and I forgot to put the OR REPLACE